# Push notifications on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a really big problem with Firebase Notifications;
my problem is that i can receive notification in background mode and foreground mode, but if I terminate it(kill it from the ram) I can't receive anything.

I found that if I comment this function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

I can receive a notification when i reopen the application after it's terminated, but i can't get a notification in background like before.

There's any way to solve it, because my application should receive notification everytime: background, foreground and when application is reopened from a terminated state

The following is an example of my notification's JSON:

```
{
"content_available": true,
"priority": "high",
"data": {
    "priority": "SILENT",
    "target": "contact",
    "msgBody": "",
    "msgTitle": ""
},
"to": "firebase_TOKEN"
```

}

I also want to say that this notification should be silent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When app is killed notification will be handled from operating system so it needs some specific key to display notification.

Like consider the below example:

```
{

"content_available": true, 
  "notification": {
    "title":  "has sent you a message", 
    "sound": "default", 
    "body": "Hi", 
    "badge": 6

  }, 
  "to": "firebase_TOKEN", 
  "priority": "high"
}
```

Here you need to replace `"data"` with `"notification"` and you also need a `"title"` instead of `"msgTitle"` and `"msgBody"` will be replaced with `"body"`.

Looks like your's is a android payload which won't work with iOS.

Comment: It's apple's way and you can not change it.

Comment: My point is with your payload it won't show on lock screen or when app is killed.

Comment: @FrancescoDestino you can accept working answer.. :)

Comment: I can give it to you a plus one right now, I don't wanna close the answer right now :)

Comment: Sure thats fine.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You must required to add `"Content-available" : "1",` in your notification to get push notification when application killed.

Comment: It works for app killed, but doesn't work when app goes in background